# Slack API : Ability to view all recently added users to Slack Channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am working on a POC to proof out the ability to get a list of all the new `users` who have been added to a specific `Slack Channel`. From my initial review of the Slack API I am not seeing anything that showcases this ability, I was curious to see if anyone had worked on something similar or could point me to resources that would be a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no ready-made API method available, that will give you that specific information. However, Slack is very flexible and you can use the existing building blocks to easily add additional features as needed.

E.g. To get the requested information you can develop a small Slack app that listens to the [`member_joined_channel`](https://api.slack.com/events/member_joined_channel) and [`member_left_channel`](https://api.slack.com/events/member_left_channel) events to keep track of when members joined a channel.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a historical record of membership in a channel, you could use the Slack API's [`groups.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.history) method, page through results, and build a membership log by looking for events of `type` [`member_joined_channel`](https://api.slack.com/events/member_joined_channel) and [`member_left_channel`](https://api.slack.com/events/member_left_channel) through time.